# how do not render component particular part in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have following code.

In my parent I rendering my child component with some props, for example:

```js
const Parent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child
        owner="Owner: Etta Bradley"
        buttonValue="10 cards"
      />
    </div>
  )
};
```

And this is my Child component:

```js
const Child = ({ owner, buttonValue) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{owner}</span>
      <input type="button" value={buttonValue} />
    </div>
  )
};
```

It working great for me, but there is some situation that I don't need `buttonValue`. Now my question is how can I do **not** render my `<input type="button" value={buttonValue} />` part for that cases? Because empty button looks very ugly.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a read of the docs for conditional rendering - in particular this part https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator to get a good understanding of how and why these patterns work. TLDR - returning a falsey value means nothing will be rendererd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're rendering based on if `buttonValue` has any data, you can use a ternary operator.

```js
const Child = ({ owner, buttonValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{owner}</span>
      { buttonValue ? <input type="button" value={buttonValue} /> : null}
    </div>
  )
};
```

Any other logic can be used in the place of the `buttonValue` boolean check.

Comment: The conditional rendering can be modified to:- `{ buttonValue && <input type="button" value={ buttonValue } /> }`

Answer (score 0):

**You will check if buttonValue is truthy**.

```
const Child = ({ owner, buttonValue }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{owner}</span>
      { 
        buttonValue && <input type="button" value={ buttonValue } /> 
      }
    </div>
  )
};
```

The input will render if buttonValue is true, if not it won't.